# bash help using EOF inside a while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, eof

I have a script, which reads some input information, line by line, then goes in loop, and then, inside loop, it creates json files with some expanded variables based on information which it takes from input information, that differs from time to time.

The issue, is that when I using cat & EOF, it breaks the while loop and reads only first line from input information.
Can you advice how to rewrite script to not to break while loop with EOF function:

```
while IFS= read -r snmp_cred; do
echo appliance $ADDM_address and $snmp_cred 
snmp_ip=$(grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})@" <<< $snmp_cred)
snmp_ip=${snmp_ip%?}
echo IP for snmp community is $snmp_ip

json_file=$DIR/cred.json
remote_dir=/some/remote/dir

cat <<EOF > $DIR/cred.json
    {
        "some", 
        "json,          
    }
EOF


[Here goes some another commands]

done <$DIR/input.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks OK, but you can avoid using `cat` altogether here. Just use `echo` or `printf`.

```
printf '\
{ 
  "ip_range" : "%s",
  "types" : [ "snmp" ],
  "description" : "%s",
  "snmp.version": "v2c",
  "snmp.port" : 161,
  "snmp.community" : "%s",
  "snmp.retries" : 3,
  "snmp.timeout" : 2 }' "$snmp_ip" "$snmp_cred" "$snmp_cred" > "$json_file"
```

In general, once you are trying to generate dynamic JSON, you have to worry about the parameter values being properly encoded. In such cases, you might want to consider generating your JSON with a tool like `jq` instead of constructing it manually.

```
jq -n --arg ipr "$ip_range" --arg cred "$snmp_cred" '{ 
  "ip_range" : $ipr,
  "types" : [ "snmp" ],
  "description" : $cred,
  "snmp.version": "v2c",
  "snmp.port" : 161,
  "snmp.community" : $cred,
  "snmp.retries" : 3,
  "snmp.timeout" : 2 }' > "$json_file"
```

Comment: The problem is that in json file I have some variables, and they not expands, when I using your approach:

Comment: Here is the json code -   {
   "ip_range" : "$snmp_ip", 
   "types" : [ "snmp" ],
   "description" : "$snmp_cred",
   "snmp.version": "v2c",
   "snmp.port" : 161,
   "snmp.community" : "$snmp_cred",
   "snmp.retries" : 3,
   "snmp.timeout" : 2
  }

Comment: Sorry, I had a few mistakes in the example; it should work now.